# Counting and summing selected number of features in map layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, layers, count

I have a map layer and I want to find out how many of one type of feature there are, and sum an associated feature. I want to do this as a plugin script as there will be a number of other operations too, this is just the starting point.

In the example below, I want to know how many instances of Virgin there are and the total KM associated with them.

I can do this as pure Python script and I can do it in Excel, but I don't know how to do it with PyQGIS.

```
 Fx   Status    KM
 Fx   Accept    32.408
 Fx   Accept    32.41
 Fx   Reject    0
 Fx   Virgin    32.413
 Fx   Virgin    24
 Fx   Accept    32.417
```

I have a working plugin and I have a filtered ComboBox to select the layer I want to interrogate, but how do I do the Count and Sum? I have a basic feature loop to get the COUNT (there must be a better way), but am stuck on the SUM.

The script I need help with it the `def CalcCDuration()` part, I have only included the `CalCTime` in case it is relevant.

*'Fx' is another feature I am using so the ComboBox only selects a certain type of layer and is of no relevance to this question beyond it being in the ComboBox script.*

```py
"""Code to Calculate time to complete workscope."""
    def CalCTime(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work."""
        if self.first_start is True:
            # self.first_start = False
            from .ocr_time_dialog import OCR_TIMEDialog
            self.dlg = OCR_TIMEDialog()

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        if self.dlg.isVisible():
            self.map_layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
            self.allow_list = [
                lyr.id() for lyr in self.map_layers if lyr.type() ==
                QgsMapLayerType.VectorLayer
                and lyr.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry
                and 'Fx' in [f.name() for f in lyr.fields()]
            ]
        self.except_list = [y for y in self.map_layers if y.id()
                            not in self.allow_list]

        self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBoxT.setExceptedLayerList(self.except_list)

        self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBoxT.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.LineLayer)

        self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.CalCDuration)

    def CalCDuration(self):
        """Calculate the duration of the particular survey type"""
        # TurnT = float(self.dlg.TurnBox.text())
        # Kn = float(self.dlg.KnBox.text())
        # Ms = float(self.dlg.MsBox.text())

        
        #Get line Km and Number from chosen layer
        global TLayer
        TLayer = self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBoxT.currentLayer()
        exp = QgsExpression('Status ILIKE \'%Virgin%\'')
        request = QgsFeatureRequest(exp)
        NoV = 0
        NoK = 0
        for feature in TLayer.getFeatures(request):
            NoV = NoV+1             
        
        self.dlg.SolBox.setText(str(NoV))
```

Comment: summation usually requires adding the relevant attribute of each feature in the loop to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further investigation and borrowing from a number of answers on this site has given me a working plugin.
The relevant section I needed to resolve is now working. The key was to use the `f.attributes` in conjunction with the `layer.dataProvider`

```
"""Get line Km and Number from chosen layer."""
TLayer = self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBoxT.currentLayer()
Kmidx=TLayer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('Designed km')
expV = QgsExpression('Status ILIKE \'%Virgin%\'')
expT = QgsExpression('Status ILIKE \'%TBC%\'')
expR = QgsExpression('Status ILIKE \'%Reject%\' AND ''Format ILIKE \'%Rerun%\'')
expI = QgsExpression('Status ILIKE \'%Virgin%\' AND ''Format ILIKE \'%Infill%\'')
requestV = QgsFeatureRequest(expV)
requestT = QgsFeatureRequest(expT)
requestR = QgsFeatureRequest(expR)
requestI = QgsFeatureRequest(expI)
NoV=0
NoT=0
NoI=0
NoR=0
KoV=0
KoT=0
KoI=0
KoR=0
for f in TLayer.getFeatures(requestV):
    KoV+=f.attributes()[Kmidx]
    KoV=round(KoV,3)
    NoV=NoV+1
for f in TLayer.getFeatures(requestT):
    KoT+=f.attributes()[Kmidx]
    KoT=round(KoT,3)
    NoT=NoT+1
for f in TLayer.getFeatures(requestI):
    KoI+=f.attributes()[Kmidx]
    KoI=round(KoI,3)
    NoI=NoI+1    
for f in TLayer.getFeatures(requestR):
    KoR+=f.attributes()[Kmidx]
    KoR=round(KoR,3)
    NoR=NoR+1
```

---

**Improved version** :

```py
t_layer = self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBoxT.currentLayer()
field_km_idx = t_layer.fields().indexFromName("Designed km")
requests_expressions = {
    "V": "Status ILIKE '%Virgin%'",
    "T": "Status ILIKE '%TBC%'",
    "R": "Status ILIKE '%Reject%' AND Format ILIKE '%Rerun%'",
    "I": "Status ILIKE '%Virgin%' AND Format ILIKE '%Infill%'",
}
results = {}

for request_name, expression in requests_expressions.items():
    request = QgsFeatureRequest(QgsExpression(expression))
    data = [f[field_km_idx] for f in t_layer.getFeatures(request)]
    results[request_name] = {"Ko": round(sum(data), 3), "No": len(data)}
```

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a more Pythonic / PyQGIS version of the code.

Comment: @J.Monticolo Thanks. How do I connect your script revision to my follow-on equations. Currently I have KoV & NoV variable which I then perform various maths functions on. In your script I only see Ko & No, how does your script provide the 8 variables? Also, I assume (req) should be (request).

Comment: I corrected the `req` into `request`, good catch ! To access you have the dict *results* : `results["V"]["Ko"]` and `results["V"]["No"]` (for the *V* request).

Comment: @J.Monticolo, found the dict and can now see what is being created (also explains why Ko and not KoV in the your last line of script, which I didn't initially understand).

Comment: I have accepted my own answer, as I it is not possible to accept @J.Monticolo 'Improved version'. The final code will be based on a combination of both.

Comment: I totally agree, you gave the good answer, I just proposed a refactor version !